# Remote Desktop doesn't work after upgrade?

Tags: 10.10, remote-desktop, vnc, vino

After upgrade Ubundu 10.04 to 10.10, remote desktop doesn't work anymore. I've checked the settings (vino-preferences) and everything is Ok, but I still can't access remotely to the machine! Any solution?

Comment: Are you able to connect with another 10.04 machine (or a livecd)? Make sure the other end is still working correctly.

Comment: I've tried 3 fresh install and connect with Ubuntu 10.04, Windows XP, without success. I couldn't understand why it happens in that PC. Before that I've made an install in a different PC and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/652961) in 10.10's shipped version of vino when UPnP is involved.  Please update; we've corrected that bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried 3 fresh install and connect with Ubuntu 10.04, Windows XP, without success. I couldn't understand why it happens in that PC. Before that I've made an install in a different PC and it works fine.

Comment: It is better to move this answer as a comment under the question. You may copy and paste this as a comment there and delete this answer.